# Trying to send data from server A to server B using Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to send data generated from server A to server B using Kafka.

So! here is what I did :
- server A : run zookeeper, bootstrap server, producer
- server B : consumer

To my understanding, having producer keep sending data to a specific serverA_IP:port in server A, consumer should be able to reach out to that serverA_IP:port and grab message but it's not working so well for me.

Am I missing out something? Maybe I need to run zookeeper and server on server B as well?

Thank you so much in advnace.

Comment: Could you give us more details on your cluster setup. You run Kafka broker and zookeeper only on server A right? How do you run exactly your consumer? If you set the bootstrap-server parameter of consumer to the same broker-list of your producer, should be good yes.. But might need more info from you in order to help

Comment: Do both servers belong to the same cluster or are you trying to send messages to a different Kafka Cluster?

Comment: @Yannick Yes I run broker and zookeeper only on server A.
I referenced this webpage : https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart
So the commands I used to make zookeepr, server, topic and a producer are :
> bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
> bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
> bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list serverA_IP:9092 --topic test

In all the configuration files, I switched all the 'localhost' to 'serverA_IP'

Comment: @Yannick and for a consumer, I used :

> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server serverA_IP:9092 --topic test --from-beginning

this seems to work when I use only insider the server A but when I try to just move the consumer to server B, it seems to not work

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Sorry my knowledge is short but I have run kafka zookeeper and a broker on server A and haven't really run any broker or a zookeeper on server B. Maybe this means server B is not part of a kafka cluster? I thought maybe if I could just run the consumer on server B and desginate the host:port to the same host:port I used when I was sending data just in server A, things should work. I am studying about Kafka and coding at the same time but I'm pretty new to computer science so it's not so easy.. I have also made topic only on server A, could this be a problem too?

Comment: `but when I try to just move the consumer to server B, it seems to not work`... What happens? Do you have an error message or does it look like the consumer on server B is waiting to get some messages?

Comment: Could you do a 'telnet IPserverA 9092' on your server B and give us the output?

Comment: By default, Kafka is only exposed locally. You need to set `advertised.listeners` in the properties such that it is an address that "server B" knows about

Comment: @ValBonn It says there is no broker available when I run the consumer. It won't even start I think!

Comment: @Yannick I don't have access to the server right now but I will let you know when I get to my server! I don't want to look like I'm ignoring your comment when I'm replying everything so..

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you so much! i will try that!

Comment: @cricket_007 oh and do you mind if I ask which properties file you are refering to?

Comment: Kafka server properties